# NetSuite employee Saved Search needs to return employee superior internal ID

Tags: sql, netsuite

I have an employee saved search that needs to return the internal ID of the {supervisor} field, by default it displays the employee ID (not internal ID) and the supervisors full name.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try using formula,set value {supervisor.id}

Comment: Please be more clear with your question. State what system you are using etc. Also use tags.

Answer (score 3):

Scroll down to the bottom of the field selection list and find "Supervisor fields...", then select "Internal ID" from the ensuing popup.

This is how you do JOINs in the search UI.

Comment: i do not see "supervisor fields..." as an option. Is there a way to "turn" that on?

Answer (score 0):

{supervisor.id} will work with out any doubt see below:
[image]